# sunspot solr 404 error

Tags: solr, sunspot

I am working on updating our applications servers and I have run into an issue I have never seen before.

I have ensured that the server is up and running, I can view the admin web interface.

When I attempt to index data using the rails console and this command User.index, I get the following error from sunspot/solr

```
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: NOT_FOUND
Backtrace: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:230:in `adapt_response'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:167:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
(eval):2:in `post'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:87:in `add'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:101:in `add_documents'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `add'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot.rb:184:in `index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:230:in `adapt_response'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:167:in `execute'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
from (eval):2:in `post'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rsolr-1.0.8/lib/rsolr/client.rb:87:in `add'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:101:in `add_documents'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `add'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot-1.3.3/lib/sunspot.rb:184:in `index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.2.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:491:in `block in index_with_trace_SolrClient_Sunspot_index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.2.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.2.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:486:in `index_with_trace_SolrClient_Sunspot_index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:256:in `block (2 levels) in solr_index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:345:in `solr_benchmark'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:255:in `block in solr_index'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:69:in `find_in_batches'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:443:in `find_in_batches'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:254:in `solr_index'
from (irb):2
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Double check if your query correctly hits `<host>:<port>/solr/update`

Comment: @aitchnyu same issue, how to check that?

Comment: @Rubytastic I would check the server logs for requests generated by it, like `POST solrapp/update` and see if they got error response. In Tomcat, its a file `catalina.out`. I never used Ruby, hence my comment was about checking the Solr side of things. Please leave an answer yourself when you solve it. I myself never expected this forgotten comment to get responses after a full year :-)